# Bit Twiddling in C - computes 2 times x or returns largest signed number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am writing a function that computes 2 times the parameter x, but if it overflows it should return the largest positive or negative signed number. The problem is I can only use `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`. *32-bit integers* are involved.

This is what I have so far:

```
int boundedMult(int x){
    int xSign = x>>31
    int y = x << 1; // Multiply by 2
    int signBit = y>>31; // Capture the signBit of the answer
    int shift = signBit; 
    shift |= shift<<1; // Make shift all 1 or 0 depending on the sign bit
    shift |= shift<<2;
    shift |= shift<<4;
    shift |= shift<<8;
    shift |= shift<<15;
    int answer = ~signBit<<31 | shift; // 01111... If signBit=1 and 1000... If signBit=0
}
```

Seems fine, right? I also **can't use any constants outside of an unsigned byte (0-255) inclusive**. I've tried so many approaches but I end up breaking one of these rules in all of them.

Comment: So you only need to check if x * 2 overflows?

Comment: To see if the result will overflow, all you have to do is see if the two high-order bits are different in the original number.  If they are, then the result overflows:  10* is a negative number that overflows when doubled, and 01* is a positive number that overflows when doubled.  If the two high-order bits are the same (00* or 11*), then the number remains positive (or remains negative) and there is no overflow.

Comment: Yes, and if it does I have to return either −2147483648 or 2147483647 depending on the sign.

Comment: Detecting overflow isn't as big as an issue as returning the right value if it does overflow. If a positive # overflows I have to return the largest 32-bit positive # and vice versa for a negative number. Getting the bits to move to the proper position that works for both rules is what I'm having the biggest issues on

Comment: There are problems here. First, you compute the multiplication and then throw away the original. That means it's already too late to know whether you overflowed, because that condition is signified in this case by the signs of `x` and `x << 1` being different. Then you shift right by 31, which is almost surely part of the solution, but keep in mind that that can be an arithmetic right shift, so you probably want to mask it (the shift/or chain is useless otherwise).

Comment: How do you know min/max of int without using a constant?

Comment: @user3528438 I can use constants just not big ones

Comment: The range of all types are implementation defined, there's no reliably way to know the limits other than asking the compiler in `limits.h`

Comment: For this assignment, are you allowed to assume 32-bit integers?

Comment: @harold I adjusted the error you gave me I think, but what do you mean by wanting to mask it? I don't understand "the shift/or chain is useless otherwise"

Comment: If you assume 32-bit integers (as your code appears to do), then you can solve this with some building blocks.  You can generate min_int as (1 << 31), and max_int as ~min_int.  And the normal case is just x << 1.  You then need to select one of these based on the overflow conditions.  The sign bit is ((x >> 31) & 1).  Overflow is (((x ^ (x >> 1)) >> 30) & 1).  These values are both 0 or 1.  Subtract 1 (which is the same as adding -1, which is just ~0).  That gives you two full-word masks (all 0 or all 1).  Invert if needed.  Then just use & to select the answer and | to combine them.

Comment: @Tom Karzes Thank you so much! You have given me so much already, but I'm sorry I have one more question if that's alright. I'm very new to all this and find it very confusing.  How exactly does & help you select and | combine?

Comment: Like this:  `(mask & val1) | (~mask & val2)`.  If `mask` is all 1's then you will get `val1`.  If `mask` is all 0's then you will get `val2`.

Comment: What is mask?val1 being 1000 and val2 being 0111?

Comment: Um - I explained all this, in tedious detail.  Mask is either all 0 bits (i.e., 0) or all 1 bits (i.e., -1).  Just think about it.  This is very, very elementary stuff.  If you bitwise-AND all zeros with something, the result is 0.  If you bitwise-AND all ones with something, the result is that thing.  That's way more than enough for you to go on.

Comment: Example, in 4 bits:  if val1 is 0101 and val2 is 0011, then there are 2 cases:  (1) if mask is 1111, the result is (1111 & 0101) | (0000 & 0011) which is 0101, i.e. val1.  (2) if mask is 0000, the result is (0000 & 0101) | (1111 & 0011) which is 0011, i.e. val2.  It's obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed you can use the `!` operator, that makes this much easier.  It makes it a lot easier to generate the masks.

Comment: Is this really a homework problem?  If not, this question belongs on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange (codegolf.stackexchange.com) because the restrictions you gave in the problem were not chosen for performance, correctness, security, maintainability, or readability reasons, or due to hardware limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting challenge! Here's my solution, I hope I didn't violate any of the constraints by mistake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// work with uint to avoid undefined behavior (signed int overflow is undefined)
static inline int32_t x2(int32_t v) {
    uint32_t uv = v;
    // our first option: "multiply" by shifting:
    uint32_t doubled = uv<<1;

    // our second option: clamp to max/min integer:
    uint32_t neg     = !!(uv >> 31); // 1 if negative
    uint32_t bigval  = (~0u)>>1;     // 0x7fffffff
    uint32_t clamped = bigval + neg; // 0x80000000 if neg, 0x7fffffff otherwise

    // so, which one will we use?
    uint32_t ok   = !((v>>31) ^ (v>>30)); // 0 if overflow, 1 otherwise
                                          // note the use of signed value here
    uint32_t mask = (~ok)+1; // 0x00000000 if overflow, 0xffffffff otherwise

    // choose by masking one option with ones, the other with zeroes
    return (mask & doubled) | ((~mask) & clamped);
}

static inline void check(int32_t val, int32_t expect) {
    int32_t actual = x2(val);
    if ((val & 0x3ffffff) == 0) {
        printf("0x%08x...\n", val);
    }
    if (actual != expect) {
        printf("val=%d, expected=%d, actual=%d\n", val, expect, actual);
    }
}

int main() {
    int32_t v = 0x80000000;

    printf("checking negative clamp...\n");
    for (; v < -0x40000000; ++v) {
        check(v, 0x80000000);
    }

    printf("checking straight double...\n");
    for(; v < 0x40000000; ++v) {
        check(v, 2*v);
    }

    printf("checking positive clamp...\n");
    for(; v < 0x7fffffff; ++v) {
        check(v, 0x7fffffff);
    }
    check(0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff);

    printf("All done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And it seems to work fine:

```
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic bounded.c -o bounded && ./bounded
checking negative clamp...
0x80000000...
0x84000000...
0x88000000...
0x8c000000...
0x90000000...
0x94000000...
0x98000000...
0x9c000000...
0xa0000000...
0xa4000000...
0xa8000000...
0xac000000...
0xb0000000...
0xb4000000...
0xb8000000...
0xbc000000...
checking straight double...
0xc0000000...
0xc4000000...
0xc8000000...
0xcc000000...
0xd0000000...
0xd4000000...
0xd8000000...
0xdc000000...
0xe0000000...
0xe4000000...
0xe8000000...
0xec000000...
0xf0000000...
0xf4000000...
0xf8000000...
0xfc000000...
0x00000000...
0x04000000...
0x08000000...
0x0c000000...
0x10000000...
0x14000000...
0x18000000...
0x1c000000...
0x20000000...
0x24000000...
0x28000000...
0x2c000000...
0x30000000...
0x34000000...
0x38000000...
0x3c000000...
checking positive clamp...
0x40000000...
0x44000000...
0x48000000...
0x4c000000...
0x50000000...
0x54000000...
0x58000000...
0x5c000000...
0x60000000...
0x64000000...
0x68000000...
0x6c000000...
0x70000000...
0x74000000...
0x78000000...
0x7c000000...
All done!
```

Using [this handy interactive compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/), we can get disassembly for various platforms. Annotated ARM64 assembly:

```
x2(int):
        asr     w1, w0, 30         # w1 = v >> 30
        cmp     w1, w0, asr 31     # compare w1 to (v>>31)
        csetm   w1, eq             # w1 = eq ? 0 : -1
                                   # --- so w1 is "mask"
        mov     w2, 2147483647     # w2 = 0x7fffffff
        mvn     w3, w1             # w3 = ~w1
                                   # --- so w3 is ~mask
        add     w2, w2, w0, lsr 31 # w2 = w2 + (v>>31)
                                   # --- so w2 is "clamped"
        and     w2, w3, w2         # w2 = w3 & w2
        and     w0, w1, w0, lsl 1  # w0 = w1 & (v << 1)
        orr     w0, w2, w0         # w0 = w2 | w0
        ret                        # return w0
```

Looks pretty efficient to me. Pretty sweet that "doubled" is never saved to a register -- it's simply done as a shift on the input value for one of the and instructions.

Comment: You're using the operator `-`, but the problem only allows `~`. Luckily the conversion is trivial (`~`, `+1`).

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to post complete code solutions to homework assignments.  Suggestions for how to approach the problem are much better.

Comment: Oh, it's homework? I thought it was more of a brain teaser thing. Seems kind of unreasonable to give out as homework; intricate bit twiddling like this is not something you see often.

Comment: You could optimize it a bit more by getting rid of `!`: The first two for `neg` are not needed, and for the other you can first xor and then shift, and invert the logic to use an overflow flag.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
int boundedMult(int x)
{
    int xSign = (x >> 31) & 1;
    int resultArray[] = {x + x, x + x, ~(1 << 31), 1 << 31};
    int willOverflow = xSign ^ ((x >> 30) & 1);
    return resultArray[(willOverflow << 1) + xSign];
}
```

Just as *@Tom Karzes* wisely pointed out in comment, "To see if the result will overflow, all you have to do is see if the two high-order bits are different in the original number."

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to use control statements.

Comment: You need to use bitwise masks and ors to get around it, as I outlined in the comments before people started posting code solutions.

Comment: @TomKarzes Answer updated. Old `resultArray` trick, but it's really useful!

Comment: I really don't think using memory lookups is considered a valid solution.  If I were grading the problem, I would definitely take major points off for that.  Try to understand the intent:  You are given a set of operators, *and nothing more*, with which to solve the problem.  You went outside those restrictions.

Comment: @TomKarzes I was just trying to find a different approach to solve this problem. Well, maybe you're right understanding the intent.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without knowing how many bits there are in an int. An overflow means the sign bit changes if you *2 then /2.  The change can be detected by xor and ends up being min int in 2's complement.

```
int t2(int v)
{
    int v2=v<<1;        // *2
    int ovfl=(v2>>1)^v; // smallest negative # if overflow or 0 if not
    return (ovfl&v)+(~ovfl&~!!(ovfl&~v)+1)+((~!ovfl+1)&v2);
}
```

or

```
template<class T> T t2(T v)
{
    T v2=v<<1;        // *2
    T ovfl=(v2>>1)^v; // smallest negative # if overflow or 0 if not
    return (ovfl&v)+(~ovfl&~!!(ovfl&~v)+1)+((~!ovfl+1)&v2);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `ovfl?ovfl:v2` is allowed.

Comment: I'm getting 0x80000000 for positive overflow (e.g. v=0x40000000) instead of 0x7fffffff.

Comment: @Falk That is true.  I had left it as an exercise because I thought this was a homework question.  I've decided to post an answer since it would only be clear to someone who could write it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, it's not the best approach, and it can be optimized, but this approach is easy to explain.  And the optimizations are reasonably straightforward.

```
int boundedMult(int x){
  int ans = x << 1;
  // if the sign bit between ans and x is different an overflow occured
  int ansSign = (ans >> 31) & 1;
  int xSign = (x >> 31) & 1;
  // but we can't use branching, so instead let's construct a number
  int overflowed = ansSign ^ xSign;
  // let's shift this up to the signbit
  overflowed <<= 31;

  // And let's subtract 1 to make it INTMAX or -1, we're doing this because -1
  // is all 1s, so we can OR this later on.
  overflowed += ~1+1;

  // now overflowed contains INTMAX if an overflow has occured and -1 otherwise
  // but we want -INTMAX if x is negative, we do this by taking the complement of
  // overflowed if xSign is set.  A way to take the complement is to xor by
  // -1. How can we make a negative 1?

  // Four possibilities for xSign and ansSign at this point:
  // ansSign xSign Meaning
  //       0     0 x positive no overflow
  //       1     0 x positive overflow
  //       1     1 x negative no overflow
  //       0     1 x negative overflow
  // We want to detect the case "x negative overflow" without detecting any
  // other case, and we want to generate a negative 1, generating a 0 for all
  // other cases.

  // ansSign xSign -(!ansSign & xSign)
  //       0     0        0
  //       1     0        0
  //       1     1        0
  //       0     1       -1

  overflowed ^= ~(!ansSign & xSign) + 1;

  // Now overflowed contains INTMAX, -INTMAX or 0 as appropriate, so let's
  // rename it

  int aproposMaxIfOverflowed = overflowed;

  // But there's one other problem.  We only want to overwrite ans if an
  // overflow happened So because -(ansSign ^ xSign) is either all 1s if an
  // overflow occured or all zeros if it hasn't we can use it to blank or keep
  // numbers

  // This contains all 1s or ans
  int ansIfNotOverflowed = ans | (~(ansSign ^ xSign) + 1);

  // So now we have ansIfNotOverflowed, and aproposMaxIfOverflowed, we can
  // combine these now

  return ansIfNotOverflowed & aproposMaxIfOverflowed;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `-=`, which is subtraction.  Read the problem.  It's also frowned upon to post code solutions to homework problems. Suggestions are much better.

Comment: It's trivial to rewrite as `+= -1`, and apparently addition is allowed.  And while I appreciate not wanting to post a code solution to a homework problem, I left more than enough comments explaining the solution so that it can be a learning experience if the student so chooses.

Comment: Unary negation isn't allowed either.  It needs to be rewritten as ~x + 1.

Comment: Thank you, that has been fixed.

Comment: You overflow signed integers, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @starblue, yes, but this answer already relies on 2s complement representation, and 32-bit wide integers, which are also not required and defined by C spec.  If being strictly conforming is an issue in your use case, then you can simply define `overflowed` to be an unsigned integer, but only a pathological compiler would mangle the assembly generated.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity You need to distinguish implementation defined behavior and undefined behavior. Implementation defined behavior is mostly OK and behaves like you would expect for 2s complement representation. But integer overflow is undefined behavior, which allows the compiler to do anything it wants. Recent versions of GCC are quite aggressive about this.

Comment: I'm very aware of the difference, and more importantly I'm also aware of why it's undefined and how it's leveraged in optimization. This case is not one where gcc or clang does something unintended. I know because I've tested it.